# How can I spool data from SQL Server to an Excel file in different sheets

Tags: sql-server, excel

I have already implemented spooling the result of a SQL Server database query to a .csv file using the `SPOOL` command.

How can I spool multiple query results into different sheets of an Excel file?

`.CSV` file doesn't support different sheets like that of Excel since it is flat.

Comment: `spool` is not a SQL Server command.

Answer (score 3):

You'll need to use a tool alongside sql-server like like SSIS:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/sql-server-integration-services?view=sql-server-ver15

Or DTS:

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/96101955-e5ee-464c-8a5f-2edc5b0f5052/exporting-data-to-excel-sheet-through-dts-package-in-sqlserver-2000?forum=sqldataaccess

Comment: This should be an automated job to fetch the data result and copy it to excel.

Comment: Same answer applies. You'll need to use one of those tools (or another one). Excel is a very different format than csv.

Comment: This should have been in your original question. Can you please also confirm that this is SQL Server? `spool` is an Oracle command, not a SQL Server command